# TOAD Automation Designer Export to Excel utilizing Variables

Tags: oracle, automation, designer, toad, quest

My goal is to iterate over a set of oracle database instances and export a dataset to an excel file. Each instance shall be encapsulated in its own sheet. The sheet shall be named like the currently used database.

I have achieved to iterate over a selection of connections (using the *Control* -> *Connection Iterator*) and export the result set of the SQL statement to specific sheets (using *Import/Export* -> *Export Dataset* set to Excel Instance).

What I am currently struggling with is to name the sheets (currently the naming is Sheet 1, Sheet 2.....)

As far as I understood it, Automation Designer has variables. Looking at *Control* -> *Test Variable* there seem to be predefined Variables. One is *ACTIVESESSIONDB* which is exactly what I want.

**How can I tell Export Dataset to use the variable ACTIVESESSIONDB to name the sheets?**

Unssuccessful tries include:

- #ACTIVESESSIONDB
- %ACTIVESESSIONDB%
- %ACTIVESESSIONDB

[image: Example of how the variable is set in the dialog]

Answer (score 0):

%ACTIVESESSIONDB% should work, but variables are not supported in the "Sheet Name" field, so it does not.   You could use %ACTIVESESSIONDB% in the fieldname field, for example.

We can add that in the next Toad version.

By the way, Stack Overflow is great, but you'll probably get quicker answers about Toad in Toad's forum.

https://forums.toadworld.com/c/toad-for-oracle/10